# Display readable output from subprocess check_output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, output, tokenize

How can I make my output from `subprocess.check_output(args, "command")` readable by humans? I have researched this topic, and have found how to "tokenize" but not *erm..* "de-tokenize" the output.
My example code below is relatively what I'm after, but to explain better, when I print the string that `string = subprocess.check_output(...)` feeds out, it is nearly unintelligible.

**Code:**

```
from subprocess import *
readOutput = check_output(
    "dir",
    shell = True)
print(readOutput)`
```

**Output:**

```
b' Volume in drive C has no label.\r\n Volume Serial Number is 2AAE-9786\r\n\r\n Directory of C:\\Users\\spike\\Documents\\GitHub\\GitterGUI\\example\r\n\r\n10/19/2015  06:29 PM    <DIR>          .\r\n10/19/2015  06:29 PM    <DIR>          ..\r\n10/19/2015  06:29 PM                60 batfile.bat\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image.bmp\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM                22 New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM    <DIR>          New folder\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM    <DIR>          New folder (2)\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document (2).txt\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document (3).txt\r\n10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document.txt\r\n10/19/2015  06:27 PM                96 script.py\r\n               7 File(s)            178 bytes\r\n               4 Dir(s)  819,483,295,744 bytes free\r\n'
```

**It should be:**

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2AAE-9786

 Directory of C:\Users\spike\Documents\GitHub\GitterGUI\example

10/19/2015  06:29 PM    <DIR>          .
10/19/2015  06:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/19/2015  06:29 PM                60 batfile.bat
10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Bitmap Image.bmp
10/19/2015  06:26 PM                22 New Compressed (zipped) Folder.zip
10/19/2015  06:26 PM    <DIR>          New folder
10/19/2015  06:26 PM    <DIR>          New folder (2)
10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document (2).txt
10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document (3).txt
10/19/2015  06:26 PM                 0 New Text Document.txt
10/19/2015  06:27 PM                96 script.py
               7 File(s)            178 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  819,481,882,624 bytes free
```

As you can see, my script needs serious work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print((readOutput).decode('utf-8'))`
instead of `print(readOutput)`

The issue was that the output to the string `readOutput` was not Unicode format.

**Edit:**

I liked the response:

> "Alternatively, pass `universal_newlines=True` to `check_output` to make it decode automatically."

– [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger)

Comment: Alternatively, pass `universal_newlines=True` to `check_output` to make it decode automatically.

Comment: Great! How could I add that into my answer without getting banned off this place?

Comment: Huh? Go ahead and add it if you like; it's fine to elaborate. I was just pointing out the way to implicitly convert to `str` instead of getting `bytes`, then converting explicitly.